# why does wheel generate egg-info folder?

Tags: python-3.x, python-wheel

I am using `wheel` to build my package using this command which is supposed to generate built distribution package:

> python setup.py bdist_wheel

It indeed generated a `dist/packagename.whl` under root folder but meanwhile it also generated `packagename.egg-info` under `src` folder, as show below:

```
package
   | dist
      packagename.py3-none-any.whl
   | src
      | packagename.egg-info
      | codes
   setup.py
```

So my question is why `packagename.egg-info` is generated under `src`?

Comment: This is just an intermediate step of executing `setup.py`. You could use `pip wheel --no-deps .` instead if it bothers you.